# Do Oracle SQL DBs Remove duplicate entries in a where-in clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-in

I apologize if this is a duplicate question: I've searched but finding many non-related topics/questions.

For instance

```
select * 
from table_of_things 
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1)
```

Will Oracle pre-processing remove the duplicates before performing the query? How can I find out? I imagine in large lists the performance loss can be huge and it would be good to remove duplicates myself before querying if not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you, I couldn't find any specific documentation entry that specifies if the expression list gets simplified for performance reasons. It must be considered an implementation detail.  But based on observation, it does appear like the optimizer performs the optimization.

On Oracle 12c, I ran an example query much like yours with `autotrace` turned on, and it listed the filter predicates it used. As expected, the list of predicates was simplified to eliminate the duplicates.

Use `autotrace` on your query if you want to check it out for yourself.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much. I will pursue the `autotrace` output--I'm not using 12c, currently!

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  Or, more relevantly, it is a totally unimportant question *how* the logic is implemented.

`IN` follows simple logic.  It evaluates to true when the left operand is in the list following the `IN`.  It evaluates to equally true when the operand is in the list multiple times.

In practice, I'm guessing that Oracle does remove duplicates during the compiling phase.  But, the definition of `IN` is the same regardless of whether or not duplicates are present.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I understand the logic is the same, that is to be expected, but my question is for efficiency concerns in large `IN` clauses. Given your guess, is there a way to verify this is the case, per the second part of my question?