# Fill range table from internal table without duplicates

Tags: performance, abap

I wonder what's usually faster:

- Filter out duplicates and then do the select
  or
- Do the select directly with duplicates

I think it may be the first one but I don't know -
**how to nicely and efficiently integrate the deletion of duplicates in my code?**

```
DATA:
  lt_itab       TYPE TABLE OF string,
  lt_range_itab TYPE RANGE OF string
  .

* Populating itab with duplicates
* Can the following somehow become a neat one-liner? This is ugly!
APPEND '1'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '2'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '2'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '3'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '4'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '4'  TO lt_itab.

*Populating range table from itab
*Should one remove the duplicates here for a performance boost in the upcoming select?
*If so - how?
*-------------------------------------------------------
lt_range_itab = VALUE #(
  FOR <ls_itab> IN lt_itab
  ( sign = 'I'
    option = 'EQ'
    low = <ls_itab> )
).

*...or is such a select usually faster than the time it takes to remove the duplicates?
*-------------------------------------------------------
*SELECT *
*  FROM       anyTable
*  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_new_data)
*  WHERE      anyProperty NOT IN @lt_range_itab.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many questions... :-)

*Edit: I revised this answer after the discussions in the answers*

> What's usually faster?

Good databases will select fast even if there are *some* duplicates in the range. 
[Oracle's optimizer, for example, removes duplicates on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666282/do-oracle-sql-dbs-remove-duplicate-entries-in-a-where-in-clause). SAP HANA, in comparison, may get slower, but its dictionary-based architecture will usually keep it on a negligible level. So generally, I see no imperative to remove duplicates before each and every query.

However, things may go awry if the optimizer is sub-optimal and there is a large number of duplicates. So if you *expect* duplicates, it may be better to keep to the safe side and remove them before the query.

Also note that range tables have a length restriction. They are translated to a SQL statement with an `IN` clause, and SQL statement strings have a maximum number of characters. Duplicate removal thus may be a necessary strategy to get the query working at all.

Longer ranges can be converted to `FOR ALL ENTRIES`, which packetizes the query and allows for much longer ranges. However, that statement form leads to multiple roundtrips with the database, and will *definitely* suffer from duplicates in the query.

> Can the following somehow become a neat one-liner?

```
DATA(lt_itab) = VALUE string_table( ( `1` ) ( `2` ) ( `2` ) ( `3` ) ( `4` ) ( `4` ) ).
```

Or right away as suggested by Sandra below:

```
SELECT ... WHERE anyProperty NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

> If so - how?

```
SORT lt_range_tab.
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_range_tab.
```

**Last but not least,** note that an `anyProperty IN @lt_range_tab` may be considerably faster than the reversed `NOT IN` variant. Databases tend to keep *positive* indexes which respond best to positive queries. If you have the possibility, e.g. because you're filtering a field with fixed value list, it may be worthwhile to reverse the filter before sending it to the database.

Comment: thx, and sorry for the many questions! This answer is exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: **1)** I don't agree for "no need to remove duplicates", I explain why in a separate answer **2)** this writing is also possible `SELECT ... WHERE anyProperty NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')`, or use constants instead of literals if your prefer (PS: I agree that NOT should be avoided as a rule-of-thumb, but it may be handled very well by the database -depends on many parameters-, so if no other choice then performance tests will confirm whether it's okay or not)

Comment: Sandra is definitely right about the FOR ALL ENTRIES. It may result in additional round trips with the database and worsen performance. But ranges result in IN clauses - which are very different. Whether they’re slower depends on the optimizer. SAP HANA will not be slower, due to its dictionary architecture. Oracle’s DB neither, due to its strong optimizer, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666282/do-oracle-sql-dbs-remove-duplicate-entries-in-a-where-in-clause.

Comment: Okay for performance, but you still need to reduce the size of the IN values because of the eventual maximum length of the query (depends on the database as always), so still go for removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is faster of course, because the database operations with physical disks are much slower than in-memory operations.

Is the impact on performance noticeable is another question ; it depends on the number of duplicate selections and on the volume of data.

One well known example is the `SELECT ... FOR ALL ENTRIES` construct which can have a big impact on performance if the duplicates are not removed, because ABAP internally converts it into several SELECT, and so the same data may be selected several times (which is removed at ABAP side afterwards).

In brief, except when you are sure there is a small data volume, make sure there are no duplicates before a SELECT.

Comment: absolutely agree on that! use `sort` + `delete adjacent duplicates` => I once had (due to an error of a colling function) an input table with several ten-thousand entries, where only a couple (less than 10) where different => made a HUGE difference!!!